# How to create queue in Rabbitmq

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I am creating a new image taking base as rabbitmq and trying to create queue,exchange which will be reflected on localhost url once the server is up. I am able to manually create queue within rabbitmq container. But I want to achieve this either through dockerfile or entrypoint.sh. I want the exchange, queue to be available as soon as rabbitmq server is up. Please suggest any way to achieve it. Any sample example will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Rabbitmq has a [Management HTTP API](https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/). You can use this api to interact with rabbitmq.

You can create an exchange by doing a PUT request to `http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/${vhost}/${name}`. Similarly, you can create a queue by
doing a PUT to `http://localhost:15672/api/queues/${vhost}/${name}`.

You can call these using `curl` in the entrypoint script.

Comment: Just for information, the operation is a PUT, not a POST (as mentioned in you linked doc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HareDu 2 like so:

```
var result = _container.Resolve<IBrokerObjectFactory>()
                .Object<Queue>()
                .Create(x =>
                {
                    x.Queue("fake_queue");
                    x.Configure(c =>
                    {
                        c.IsDurable();
                        c.AutoDeleteWhenNotInUse();
                        c.HasArguments(arg =>
                        {
                            arg.SetQueueExpiration(1000);
                            arg.SetPerQueuedMessageExpiration(2000);
                        });
                    });
                    x.Targeting(t =>
                    {
                        t.VirtualHost("HareDu");
                        t.Node("Node1");
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a practical example with curl and the REST HTTP API which was already mentioned.

First of all, the HTTP REST API is a separate plugin and if not installed, you have to install it with the command:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

if you want to install it in your `Docker` image, you can do:

```
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Once you plugin is installed, you can just call the API with a curl command:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:15671/api/queues/%2F/TEST_QUEUE' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Z3Vlc3Q6Z3Vlc3Q=' \
--data-raw '{
    "auto_delete": false,
    "durable": true,
    "arguments": {}
}'
```

The Basic auth provided is guest/guest as the default user in the docker image.

The trick is for the default vhost, you have to put %2F in your url (equivalent to `/`) this can make you lose a lot of time if you try other variations.

Here are some references:

- [Management plugin documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)
- [HTTP API documentation](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/v3.10.6/deps/rabbitmq_management/priv/www/api/index.html)

If you need a practical docker example, you can have a look to my solace integration project where I set up a rabbitMQ for testing purpose [here](https://github.com/ruffp/solace-client-integrations/blob/master/docker/rabbitmq/Dockerfile).